# PulseAudio Bluetooth Speaker crash on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pulseaudio

I just bought a JBL speaker, tested it on my phone and proceeded with this tutorial on my Raspberry Pi:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/bluetooth-audio-raspberry-pi-3/

I managed to pair and trust the speaker, but I can't connect to the device from bluetoothctl, only from audio settings.

Problem is, most of the times it doesn't work. I've managed to have audio for 3 seconds in a timespan of ... 4 hours.

This is where PulseAudio crashes:

E: [pulseaudio] bluez4-util.c: org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist

I've tried a lot of things from forums, nothing worked.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but then I used a USB bluetooth adaptor for connecting to my speaker, and now I get a nice stable connection all the time.

I can't be 100% sure that this will fix your problem, but give it a try. It seems that the built in bluetooth adaptor for rasp Pi 3 isn't great. I used an Asus adaptor, but if you need to buy one, you can find a list of the officially supported adaptors @ https://www.raspberrypi.org/.

Stephen